# How to encode query parameters using apache URL rewrite rules

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, webserver

In my use case, I need to encode `{QUERY_STRING}` value and pass this value as a separate parameter. Here it is how it should work:

> http://www.example.com?param1=value1&param2=value2&param3=value3

The URL can have n number of parameters and values may contain special characters and value is an alphanumeric string.

I need to transform the URL to:

> http://www.example.com?param1=value1&param2=value2&param3=value3&**originalQP=param1=value1%26param2=value2%26param3=value3**

I added parameter called `originalQP` and it should be always encoded.

How can I get this encoded string using mod rewrite flags?

I tried using `B` and `NE` flags but neither of them worked. I am not getting '&' being encoded in the transformed URL instead `originalQP` value is being passed as `param1=value1`.

How can I get complete value?

Comment: Would `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.+)` `RewriteRule ^$ /?originalQP=%1 ` not auto encode it?

Comment: No I tried this trick as well but it didnt work. I thought %1 back reference will be encoded if I use B flag in RewriteRule but it still didnt.

Comment: Is there anyone who can give their hand in accomplishing this task?